# Is there a better way to show template's module positions?

Tags: templates, positions, cms

Does anyone know a better way to show a template's positions.

It seems to me that appending "...?tp=1" to url is rather klunky and sometimes hard to read?

Thanks!!

Comment: Best to ask the template provider as most bootstrap templates allow modification. The tp method is useful for checking what position existing modules are in

Answer (score 7):

I tend to use commercial templates, and they provide a nice graphical map I can use as a guide.

Other than that, you might want to mess with [PowerAdmin by Joomlashine](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/administration/admin-navigation/jsn-poweradmin) (It's not a template, it's an enhancement to the admin). It's got a nifty layout that lets you see the different positions and what modules are loaded in them.

Answer (score 4):

I use to create custom HTML saying the name of the position I'm putting it in, it's a great and easy way to locate all positions ;)

Then I create an ipsum article, make a menu item "special" category access for it, and assign all these test modules to appear just in that menu item

That way I have all positions, including component one, and being custom HTML I can use to make a first draft.

Answer (score 4):

I just noticed that the backend, under ***Template Manager: Styles***, has a little icon (next to the checkbox) that when clicked will preview the home page with module positions shown.