# How to know the available module positions on my template?

Tags: templates, module-display

My template has many positions where I can display modules. The problem is that they have names like featured 1, featured 2, banner 1, banner 2, user 1, user 2, user 3 and so on.

Everytime I have to create a new module, I have to try various positions to find where I will finaly place the module.

How can I find where these positions are on my template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Better way to show positions](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/69/better-way-to-show-positions)

Comment: @isherwood: How is it duplicate, since that question assumes knowledge from possible answers of this question here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Joomla Template Manager** provides an easy way to reveal the available module positions of the active template on each page.

First you have to enable the feature from the backend.
From the Admin Menu, Go to:

- **Extensions -> Template Manager.**
- Click the **Options** Button, on the Toolbar.
- In **Template Manager Options**, enable the **Preview Module Positions** (if disabled).
- **Save** the options.

With the feature enabled, you can now force Joomla to preview the module positions on each page in the front-end, you want to see the them.

Do with the following:

Add at the end of the url the "**tp=1**" parameter/value.
 - With SEF URLs enabled, add "?tp=1", at the end of your sef url.
 - With SEF disabled, add "&tp=1", at the end of the url.
 - Click enter to re-load the page with the new parameter.

Joomla will display the available module positions of this page.

#### Update:

Thanks to Lodder's feedback below, I should mention that is a good practice to disable this feature after finishing with the task of viewing the module positions.

Comment: I would also mention disabling the preview mode once you've finished with it. If I rightly remember, there was some sort of security issue with it. Whether is has been fixed, I do not know

Answer (score 4):

A Google images search for "module positions TEMPLATENAME" will often return images with available module positions. This works very well for the default Joomla templates (like Protostar, Beez etc.)

Many (most) commercial templates include an overview of available module positions. In addition, they tend to use the same positions (or only small variations) for all templates they release. Available module positions can be found in the demo-version of the template, by looking for a menu item called "Module Positions" or similar, giving a clear, schematic view of all positions.